# Use Dense_Rank to show row number in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table showed below

table_1

```
  col_a        col_b
     a           ab
     a           ab
     a           ab  
     a           bc
     b           bc
     b           bc
     b           bc
```

I want to show the row number like this

```
row_num  col_a  col_b
    1    a     ab
    1    a     ab
    1    a     ab
    2    a     bc
    3    b     bc
    3    b     bc
    3    b     bc
```

I want to structure my table looks like this. I used Dense_Rank(), by it is not working. Help will be appreciated

Here is my code.

```
DENSE_RANK() OVER (
    Partition BY col_a,col_b
            Order by 
            col_a
           ),
```

But I get this result instead.

```
row_num  col_a  col_b
    1    a     ab
    1    a     ab
    1    a     ab
    1    a     bc
    1    b     bc
    1    b     bc
    1    b     bc
```

Comment: Why not `DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col_a, col_b)`?

Comment: If you ever find yourself placing the *same* column(s) in both the `PARTITION BY` and `ORDER BY` clauses of an `OVER()` you should stop and ask yourself what you think you're trying to achieve. If it's in the `PARTITION BY` clause, then you know that, within each partition, that column always has a single value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just order by `col_a` and `col_b`:

```
WITH table_1(col_a, col_b) AS(
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
        ('a',   'ab'),
        ('a',   'ab'),
        ('a',   'ab'),
        ('a',   'bc'),
        ('b',   'bc'),
        ('b',   'bc'),
        ('b',   'bc')
    )t(a,b)
)
SELECT *,
    DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY col_a, col_b)
FROM table_1
```

Comment: Great answer, this is what I am looking for. Thank You